# What is the algorithm for tag clouds?

Tags: php, mysql, tag-cloud

I'd like to create a tag clouds, and I'm wondering based on what parameters I should do this.

Also, I don't want the same top tags to be displayed all the time, so how do big sites handle this?

I've got table that contains the items, a table that contains the tags (just tag id and tag text) and another table for normalization, with a row for each relationship between an item and a tag.

Comment: It's better to google it and check results. If you have questions about implementation, ask these questions at SO/Programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good implementation with nice flexibility (and in PHP) is WordPress's implementaion. Have a look at their argument object in the [documentation for wp_tag_cloud()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud):

- *smallest* - The smallest tag (lowest count) is shown at size 8
- *largest* - The largest tag (highest count) is shown at size 22
- *unit* - Describes 'pt' (point) as the font-size unit for the smallest and largest values
- *number* - Displays at most 45 tags
- *format* - Displays the tags in flat (separated by whitespace) style
- *separator* - Displays whitespace between tags
- *orderby* - Order the tags by name
- *order* - Sort the tags in ASCENDING fashion
- *exclude* - Exclude no tags
- *include* - Include all tags
- *topic_count_text_callback* - Uses function default_topic_count_text
- *link* - view
- *taxonomy* - Use post tags for basis of cloud
- *echo* - echo the results

That's with this code as a sample:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'smallest'                  => 8, 
    'largest'                   => 22,
    'unit'                      => 'pt', 
    'number'                    => 45,  
    'format'                    => 'flat',
    'separator'                 => \"\n\",
    'orderby'                   => 'name', 
    'order'                     => 'ASC',
    'exclude'                   => null, 
    'include'                   => null, 
    'topic_count_text_callback' => default_topic_count_text,
    'link'                      => 'view', 
    'taxonomy'                  => 'post_tag', 
    'echo'                      => true ); ?>
```